# android: how to update application with shared user id to a version without shared user id

Tags: android, manifest, upgrade

When developing an android app we found following issue in the upgrade process on the following described situation:

·Versions < 1.0 don't have android:sharedUserId declared in the manifest
·Versions later than 1.0 (1.X) have android:sharedUserId declared in the manifest.

The issue is that we found users previous to version 1.0 cannot update the application to any version >= 1.0, due to shared user incompatibilty

So we would like to do a new build removing sharedUserId to allow them to upgrade. But then we have another problem:  if we remove shared user id we found that users of version 1.0 will not be able to update to the newer versions 1.X in the future because installation fails.

How can we unify the upgrade process? Is there some trick for achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No trick, its just the way things are designed (for security reasons). Users with the wrong shared user id status may be able to fix things by first uninstalling the current apk, and then rebooting their device (though I've occassionally seen the reboot not be required).

Because of this, I *always* define a shared user id, even though I generally assume I won't need it.